# How to give the path which can be accessible in any system?

Tags: batch, batch-file

//path should be C:\Code\freshcode\projectpath

```
SET mypath=%~dp0
subst W: /d
Subst w: "%mypath:~0,-18%" 
w:

cd bin 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :_checkxpm
//code
goto:EOF


_checkxpm
cd list/abc
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

//code
goto:EOF
```

I create directoy w and pass the project pATH . Batch file unable to identified it.

Comment: easiest way, navigate to the folder first, for example `cd /d %~dp0` and then `subst W: .` which maps the current folder to w:

Comment: @LPChip,I do the same I got the error "The system cannot find the specified path"

Comment: %~dp0 only works in a batchfile. You're not typing the commands in cmd to test it, right? otherwise, maybe it failse elsewhere in the script.